# Using NSIS the Uninstaller shortcut does not show up in the Start Menu

Tags: windows, nsis, startmenu

Using NSIS I have created an installer, which works well. It is a user privileged installer which installs in %localAppData%\Programs;

```
StrCpy $INSTDIR `$LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\MyAppFolder
```

I create an uninstaller which works perfectly from Control Panel, Programs and Features.

I have created an Uninstaller shortcut using;

```
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${MUI_PRODUCT}\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe" 0
```

The ".lnk" file is created in the same place as the application shortcut;

```
C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyAppFolder
```

If I browse to this folder and double click the uninstaller link it works fine.

The application shortcut is visible in the start menu, however the Uninstaller is not. I have reviewed a few "solutions," but have been unable to resolve the issue. What kinds of issues should I look for?

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft guidelines say that you should not create shortcuts to uninstallers nor help files.

Starting with Windows 8, [Windows hides those pointless shortcuts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190319-00/?p=102342) from the start menu.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I disagree with this, but there are many things in life I do not agree with which I cannot change. So do I change the name to remove instead of uninstall, or just acquiesce to the wisdom of M$?

Comment: Just follow the guideline, just a single shortcut to your app (in the $smprograms folder).